# Why does my solid state relay not properly power a DC load?

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

I'm using a T108S02 to try to use a logical signal to turn on or off a small 3V DC toy. I'm not sure of the load current of the toy since my ammeter is not working.
When I activate the relay, my toy turns on, but appears to be running with limited load as the motor runs at about half speed.
I am expecting this SSR to be either all on or all off. What would make it act like a resistance?

Comment: I can't find the spec on that relay part number... can you double check the part number? Also, where is your voltage source coming from, i.e. the 3VDC source to the toy?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a datasheet, or the manufacturer's name?  The output of a SSR will involve transistors of some sort, and will not be a near-zero resistance like a mechanical relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An  SSR  can, in most cases, be considered to be "all off" when it's OFF, but when it's ON there'll always be some series resistance it exhibits which keeps it from being "all on".

That resistance is, most likely, what's keeping your motor performing at a level less than what you'd like it to.

EM Fields

Answer (score 2):

Solid state relay are often designed to switch AC loads and may have 1-2 volt drop which would slow the motor.  Do you have a link to the data sheet?

Normally for low voltages you would use a transistor or MOSFET to turn on a motor.  If necessary you could also use  real relay - not a solid state relay.

Comment: This SSR is designed for an AC load. I couldn't find one that specified DC and figured this might work. Guess not. I did just try the toy with a 330 ohm resistor and it won't work, so it sounds like the system is sensitive to having any other resistance in series. The datasheet for this SSR is [here](http://sharp-world.com/products/device/lineup/data/pdf/datasheet/s108t02_e.pdf)

Comment: @Jeremy.  That SSR has a triac output with a typical 1.2 v on voltage.  Do you have any details on the motor?  Small low voltage motors will usually take hundreds of milliamps so you will need something with an on resistance of an ohm or less.

Comment: I don't have any information on the motor yet. I have another toy on order that I'll be taking the guts out of anyway, but I can't take this one apart. I think your hypothesis holds water though. Thanks so much. Can you tell me how you found that? IN the DS, I see "ON-state Voltage" with a max of 1.5V. Does that mean that the load resistance in the on-state will be variable, but the voltage drop will hold approximately steady?

Comment: Figure 4 on page 6 shows how the on voltage varies with current.  Since it has a trial output stage the on voltage will not be linear with respect to current.  Also since it has a trial output stage once switched on it will not switch off until the current is reduced to below the holding current of 50mA - yet another reason why it is not suitable.